# Calling methods assignment fix via confusing instructor comment in C#

Tags: c#, methods

So a question on a quiz in my programming class is this: "Create a value returning method called squareThis() independent of but called from the test app.  This method cannot refer to any object within the application.  Rather, pass the double value dblValue to the method and place the result into lblOutput once btnProblem4 is pressed.  Have the method return dblValue squared."

I have established dblValue and called the method in a click event, specifically btn_4. I was not sure what he meant by calling it independently, and created another .cs within the program specifically for this problem. This is the code for the click event.

```
public void btnProblem4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FinalCalc c = new FinalCalc();
        lblOutput.Text = c.FinalPiece();
    }
```

This is the separate class form I created in the program:

```
namespace MethodsQuiz
{
class FinalCalc
{
    public string FinalPiece()
    {
        double Math4 = Math.Pow(1.5, 2);
        string mathfinal = Math4.ToString();
        return mathfinal;
    }
}
```

}

The instructor marked this question with this comment: "#4 problem? Don't find the method."

This is my first post, so I apologize if this is in a terrible format. I am not asking you to solve this question for me; only to explain the question and the instructors comment, as well as what I have done wrong. Again, I am not seeking you to answer this question, just to provide assistance so that I can understand. Thank you.

Comment: By "Don't find the method' I think he refers that you should have called the method squareThis() instead of FinalPiece() and you lack a parameter in the method so that you can pass the double value to do the method and do the square operation in order to return the result

Comment: I see that now, thank you so much for the help. As a beginner programmer it definitely becomes hard to keep up with the terminology and really understanding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably he meant having a self static method in the same class (in your control or Forms code behind class) and call that method in your button click event like

```
private static string FinalPiece(double dblVal)
{
    double squared = dblVal * dblVal;
    return mathfinal.ToString();
}

public void btnProblem4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  lblOutput.Text = FinalPiece(10);
}
```

Comment: Ah I see. That definitely makes a lot more  sense. Thank you very much for the assistance!